# Send JSON data from form to external page

Tags: jquery, json, post, serialization, push

The script below currently serialises the form data and display it in JSON form in a results DIV, but also want to post the data to a Web API endpoint, as a test i'm using form-data.php, but I just can't get it to work, can anyone see where i'm going wrong please?

//JAVASCRIPT

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {

    // Attach a submit handler to the form
    $( "#signUpForm" ).submit(function( event ) {


        $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('#signUpForm').serializeObject()));


        var data = $('#signUpForm').serializeArray();
        data.push({name: 'Email', value: Email});

        $.post("form-data.php", data);


        return false;

    });

});
```

i've also tried using...

```
 $.post("form-data.php",( $('#signUpForm').serialize()+'&'+$.param({ 'Email': Email })));
```

HTML FORM

```
        <form id="signUpForm" action="" method="post">

            Email:<input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="50" size="50"/> <br/>
            Username:<input type="text" name="Username" maxlength="12" size="12"/> <br/>
            First Name:<input type="text" name="FirstName" maxlength="12" size="12"/> <br/>
            Last Name:<input type="text" name="LastName" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>
            Company:<input type="text" name="Company" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>
            Role:<input type="text" name="Role" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>
            Country:<input type="text" name="Country" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>
            Company:<input type="text" name="Company" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>
            Telephone:<input type="text" name="Telephone" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>
            Security Question:<input type="text" name="SecurityQuestion" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>
            Security Answer:<input type="text" name="SecurityAnswer" maxlength="36" size="12"/> <br/>

        <p><input type="submit" /></p>
        </form>

        <h2>JSON</h2>
        <pre id="result">
        </pre>
```

Comment: Can you share the browser console log ?

Comment: (index):438 Uncaught ReferenceError: Email is not defined

Comment: you must define the variable Email before trying to play with it : `var Email="joe@joe.com";`
        `data.push({name: 'Email', value: Email});`

Comment: Can you be more specific then 'I can't get it to work'? What's not working? Your sending a ajax request, it's not visible to the user, is that your intention? Also Email is not defined.

Comment: i'm trying t send the data another temporary file as a test, but eventually it will be sent to an external website. When I check the form-data.php there is no JSON string in there, which is what will be sent.

Comment: Email should be equal to the input field 'Email'

Comment: Yes it is my intention that i the results are not visible as eventualy they will be stored in a database.

Comment: It will be sent to a Web API endpoint

Comment: Nobody gets what i'm asking?